# display picture

Tags: c#

hi everybody
i'm trying to get bmp file then display it and i should do this by get header information of bmp and load it pixel by pixel in to an array then set pixel to display bmp picture without using bitmap class.

```
enter code here
enter code here  public void display(String filename)
    {


        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        string headerCode = br.ReadChar().ToString() + br.ReadChar().ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(headerCode);
        if (headerCode == "BM")
        {
            int bfSize = br.ReadInt32();
            int bfReserved1 = br.ReadInt16();
            int bfReserved2 = br.ReadInt16();
            int bfoffbits = br.ReadInt32();
            int biSize = br.ReadInt32();
            int biWidth = br.ReadInt32();
            int biHeight = br.ReadInt32();
            int biPlanes = br.ReadInt16();
            int biBitCount = br.ReadInt16();
            int biCompression = br.ReadInt32();
            int biSizeImage = br.ReadInt32();
            int biXPelsPerMeter = br.ReadInt32();
            int biYPelsPerMeter = br.ReadInt32();
            int biClrUsed = br.ReadInt32();
            int biClrImportant = br.ReadInt32();
            int rgbRed = 0;
            int rgbGreen = 0;
            int rgbBlue = 0;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(biWidth, biHeight);
             PictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(biWidth, biHeight);

            try
            {

                PictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

i should do this but no with bitmap class and buffer , ishould get the  header of bmp file and load it in the array then read the file to get the height and width and other information that need to display bmp pixel by oixel but without using bitmap class

Comment: Could you post the code you having issues with?

Comment: You asked something similar in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444755/load-image-in-c

Comment: OK, so what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I think he could not use Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(biWidth, biHeight).. but honestly I still don't understand what he needs and why...

Comment: @sahar, if this is homework, are you sure you are not allowed to use `Bitmap` at all, or are you just not allowed to use `Bitmap.FromFile`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: don't you think this is the same closed question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444755/load-image-in-c?

Comment: @Marco probably yes, but closing as duplicate of a closed question isn't going to help. This question is slightly more clear, and still has a (small) chance of being answered.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: oh yes, you're right. I'm quite new here and I don't know if (re)posting a closed question is allowed. @sahar, give us some more detail to help you!

Comment: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(biWidth, biHeight);       >>>> i can't use bimap classes in my homework and the loop is not that i should to write beacuse of >>>rgbBlue = br.ReadByte();                         rgbGreen = br.ReadByte();                         rgbRed = br.ReadByte(); >>>>> i should set pixel by pixel but not in this way beacuse i don't have allow to use buffer in my code.

Answer (score -2):

I would load the bitmap into c# and then convert it to jpg/png etc. Bmp is not good for web as they are way to big.

Comment: He is not talking about web, and he asking to load bitmap without using Bitmap class... so how can he convert this bitmap into a jpeg manually?